# qvalue and p.adjust functions

Tags: r, bioconductor

Between the [qvalue](https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/qvalue/inst/doc/qvalue.pdf) package and the [p.adjust](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/p.adjust.html) function, which is more appropriate to use when trying to calculate the q-values of a dataset? According to the manual for the q-value package, the q-value calculated is not an adjusted p-value which is what the p.adjust function would return. There seems to be an equal amount of people that use one or the other, but I wanted to see other opinions that could help clarify what would be most appropriate to use.

Comment: "then q-value is equal to FDR" Does it mean if I use the parameter"pi0=1" in qvalue(), the outcome will be equal to adjust.P(pvalues,"BH")?
Could you explain it by citing an example?
Any answer is appreciated!Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

`p.adjust` can calculate adjusted p-values with different methods. I think you can choose Bonferroni correction and BH correction, for instance. BH correction gives you False Discovery Rate (FDR), which is one of the most commonly used I guess.

Q-value is different and cannot be calculated by `p.adjust`. The idea is that when you have many p-values to adjust, they form a distribution. If all p-values come from the null hypothesis, the p-value distribution is going to be uniform on [0, 1]. But usually, our p-values are a mixture of the null distribution and alternative distribution. The parameter $\pi_0$ describes the proportion of p-values (or tests) that comes from the null hypothesis. To calculated q-values, the algorithm first estimates $\pi_0$, then calculates the q-value.

Note that if you set $\pi_0=1$, which means that you believe all the p-values come from the null distribution, then q-value is equal to FDR.

I think most people do not know about the meaning and details of q-values and it might be sufficient to use BH procedure in most cases.